# function in Scope to exclude

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I have country and currency but when I do scope this in calculation, i want to exclude 'Other' values in Currency. I tried below both Filter and Except but they both are still giving me 'Other', just want to exclude. I would like to do this in scope. 
Please suggest.

```
SCOPE
(
    [Measures].[Amount],
    [Country].[Country Values].[Country Values].MEMBERS,
    FILTER([Currency].[Currency Values].[All].Children , 
    [Currency].[Currency Values].&[Other])
)

SCOPE
(
    [Measures].[Amount],
    [Country].[Country Values].[Country Values].MEMBERS,
    Except([Currency].[Currency Values].[All].Children , 
    [Currency].[Currency Values].&[Other])
)
```

Comment: The second SCOPE didn't work?

Comment: Your first calculation is wrong. The second calculation is not excluding the "Other" currency, but just saying "don't calculate the measure for the currency "Other" "

Comment: I am trying to solve this but still didn't solve. How 'Other' values will be excluded with Currency drag over.

Answer (score 0):

Is this definitely correct? `[Currency].[Currency Values].&[Other]`

Should it be `[Currency].[Currency Values].[Currency Values].&[Other]` ?